# SSRS calculations on a multi value report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am trying to sort out some calculations on a multi value report. Currently someone is selection multipul products and appears 4 times on the same report. The problem is that I am getting four lots of £10.80 which I don't need. Is there a way to divide £10.80 by 4 on individual lines using an expression?

Comment: what is your source? is it sql server RDBMS? if yes, then is the query properly debugged for duplicates?

Comment: Perhaps you don't have your grouping quite right? We could probably help more if you added a visual example of what you are getting and what your desired result is. Or take a picture of the table and groups  in design mode in SSRS.

Comment: @mmarie am I correct in thinking you need the source SQL groupings?

Comment: @BhupeshC We expect to see duplicates as the selections that are made have to show multipul rows for the same client but with different options.

Comment: @TitoPaterson That might be helpful if you are are doing the grouping in your SQL statement rather than in SSRS.  But if the data is repeating in your report more than in your source data, there is probably something going on in SSRS.

Comment: @mmarie I will talk with the senior developer as I am handling a lot of stuff downsteam from the base SQL code.